# MySQL Replication was working, now broken

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, replication

So a month+ ago I setup replication from one of my web servers to m local LAN servers. I had 2 local LAN servers that were slaves (quad and hex) to the master web server (falcon). For weeks the replication worked without issue.

Then I noticed earlier this week that the I/O thread wasn't running on either quad or hex. So I restarted them over and over and over again because every so often it would look like everything would run normally, for at least one of the slave, for up to several minutes. Then the I/O thread would stop working again. I have attempted to reconfigure the master on both the LAN machines via phpmyadmin and phpmyadmin reports that the slave is now connected to the master. phpmyadmin gives me the option now (that it wasn't yesterday) of synchronizing the slave DBs with the master's. I run it and in a few seconds the page stops loading but no response (error or otherwise) is given.

All of the machines involved are running a LAMP stack on Ubuntu 12.04. The web server is 12.04 server while the LAN machines are both 12.04 desktop. I suspected that I had run apt-get update/upgrade on the LAN machines while neglecting to do so on my falcon. So I ran it on all three machines this morning. Still the I/O thread won't run.

The SQL thread is always running. Occasionally, the master shows that one of the slaves (hex) is connected. But it doesn't stay connected.

Like I said this worked for weeks without issue. Then very recently stopped. So that is why I suspect something in a recent update/upgrade that broke it all.

Anyone know how to ix this?

Thanks

Added per request - my.cnf from falcon:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port            = xxxx
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = xxxx
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name

# Replication per phpmyadmin - falcon is the MASTER
server-id=8503668
log-bin=mysql-bin
log-error=mysql-bin.err

#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#

# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Also, added per request, the lines from my.cnf on quad that set it up for replication

```
# Replication per phpmyadmin
server-id=1369932901
report-host=quad
replicate-ignore-db=visits
```

The rest of the my.cnf is default except for the bind address which is quad's LAN IP 192.168.1.70. The my.cnf on hex the same way the server-id is different, report-host is hex and it ignores the visits DB. And, like quad, the bind-address is the local LAN IP of 192.168.1.60.

**Weekend Update:**
This question floated around for 4 days without an answer as to how to fix a broken replication that once worked. I've posted the my.cnf (or at least relevant sections of it) but no one has had any suggestions on what to fix. Of the 4 days this question has been around at this point 2 were weekend days so I didn't expect much.

Oddly enough last night I did a full slave start on both slaves for the 100th time and it finally took. Both slaves ran all night without issue and are now reporting that they are caught up with the master (0 seconds behind). I created a junk DB on the master to test that everything was in fact working. And it showed up in both slaves almost immediately.

I still don't have any idea why it stopped working in the first place. It was suggested that MySQL replications need be monitored frequently. Is there a good tool out there for this purpose? (The slaves are Ubuntu and I code primarily in PHP.)

Comment: How about posting a peek at the my.cnf files for each box?

Comment: I have yet to see replication run smoothly forever. Spent plenty nights up late working through these scenarios. Like MrCleanX said show us the config files.

Comment: The whole file or just the part I've changed? I use the default my.cnf, change the bind-address so that they are externally addressable. Then add a few lines to the end of the [mysqld] section. I've edited my post to include the my.cnf from falcon with some obvious edits.

Comment: @Namphibian if replication isn't stable long term then I need to find a solution. I had read many things, before implementing the replication, that suggested that it wasn't stable long term. However, I was hoping they were simply outdated...

Comment: @gabe replication will do the job it just has problems occasionally and you need to prepare for that. Nothing is perfect unfortunately and being prepared to deal with the problems is easier than finding a perfect solution. In my experience replication needs constant monitoring because the long it is in a failed state the more difficult it is to catch up.

Answer (score 0):

- If the Slave `I/O thread` is no longer running on this server, check the slave's error log for messages that may indicate why this thread may have stopped.
- Check the last 100 lines of the error log to see if that gives a clue. Usually the problem is a wrong position given in the `CHANGE MASTER TO` command. Often the easiest fix is to set up the slave again just as if it was a new slave.
  The last error can be determined by `Last Error Number` and `Last Error`
- Check whether you are able to ping/telnet to Master from a slave server.

Comment: I checked the error logs before posting. They are empty on the master and slaves. Within phpmyadmin it shows the last error and last error number whenever there is a simple SQL issue like a duplicate key - which is the error I usually see when the position to the bin file is incorrect. I could definitely set them up as new again but that would require being able to sync the DBs from Master to the Slaves again. And ultimately, if replication via MySQL isn't stable long term then I need to find a different solution.

Comment: MySQL replication is pretty stable, you just need to know how to monitor it efficiently. I suggest to set slaves as `read_only`. This variable may help prevent some unsafe writes from occurring on slaves.

Comment: Yeah, I'd thought about adding that condition to the slave user. Right now I use the DBs via a PHP class I have. That class will only allow inserts/updates/deletes to the Master. All reads (select/show) are done from the slave DBs. However, no reason not to restrict the slave user's privileges on the master.